# Adding user to WSO2 tenant returns 401 Unathorized

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to add user to a tenant. For that I did the following:

1. Created tenant in WSO2 instance
2. Generated access token based on client key and secret for the tenant service provider
3. Use generated token to execute endpoint https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/{tenantId}/api/server/v1/scims2/Users, where tenantId is id of the tenant.

After executing the endpoint, I am getting error 401 Unauthorized. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

I am not sure if it's relevant, but I noticed that when I generate access token from main WSO2 instance (not tenant), I get these scopes

```
"scope": "internal_list_tenants internal_user_mgt_create"
```

However, when I generate similar token with tenant client key and secret, with the same scopes, I see only

```
 "scope": "internal_user_mgt_create"
```

I suppose this is fine because [createUser](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/createUser) only needs this scope, but may be 401 comes from inability to get tenant that is needed with **internal_list_tenants** scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An incorrect URL is a cause for `401` response.
Here, the URL you used (`https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/{tenantId}/api/server/v1/scims2/Users`) is incorrect.

In order to create a user in a tenant named `abc.com`, you need to invoke the endpoint

```
https://localhost:9443/t/abc.com/scim2/Users
```

In general, if you want to create a user in a tenant, the endpoint is:

```
https://<host>:<port>/t/<tenant-domain>/scim2/Users
```

If no tenant is specified in the URL, it is considered as the super tenant (carbon.super) (`https://<host>:<port>/scim2/Users` equals to `https://<host>:<port>/t/carbon.super/scim2/Users`).

Having `"scope": "internal_user_mgt_create"` is sufficient to execute user creation rest API succesully. If the required scope/permissions are absent you will get `403` response.

Comment: Thank you for detailed response!